# Generate and store primitives in ArrayList dynamically

Tags: java, arraylist

I have written a function to interpolate steps between two arrays, however the number of steps required is not known until the interpolation is complete.

Here is my function:

```
int[][] interpolate(int[] source, int[] goal){

    int[] current = new int[source.length];
    ArrayList<int[]> steps = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    while(/* condition */){
        // Change value of current

        steps.add(current);
    }
    int[][] stepsArr = steps.toArray(new int[0][0]);
    return stepsArr;
}
```

I've tried using an ArrayList to store the states as I generate them, but worked out that ArrayList only stores pointers and thus the final ArrayList contained multiple pointers to the same object (the final value of current).

Is there any way to dynamically generate int[] instances to store in steps, or else otherwise generate a 2D array of integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to your usage of primitive types, but your treatment of arrays. Fix your code by adding a *copy* of your `current` array and it will work properly:

```
steps.add(Arrays.copyOf(current));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always storing the same instance of `current`. You could create a new instance for every iteration.

```
int[][] interpolate(int[] source, int[] goal){

    int[] current;
    ArrayList<int[]> steps = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    while(/* condition */){
        current = new int[source.length];
        // Change value of current

        steps.add(current);
    }
    int[][] stepsArr = steps.toArray(new int[0][0]);
    return stepsArr;
}
```

Comment: This breaks the code: OP is iteratively applying interpolation to the same array. You'd need a copy of the previous array.